# Buscar um item no json object do http response

Tags: android, json

Bem eu sou "iniciante" no android. E no meu projeto, eu estou a pegar do http reponse (com o método GET) uma string para JSONObject.

```
"{ "status":{ "d3": { "stats" : false },    "a1": { "stats" : false } } }"
```

Mas não estou a conseguir fazer a função que pega o d3/a1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo o que você precisa fazer é buscar o JSONObject e, em seguida, buscar o primeiro elemento como:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject (stringJson);
JSONObject status = obj.getJSONObject("status");
JSONObject d3 = status.getJSONObject("d3");
```

e assim vai você conseguirá pegar sempre seus valores seguindo este conceito.

> Porem sugiro que pesquise um pouco o **como converter Json** para objeto que vai facilitar muito sua vida.

Comment: A ultima linha não é suposto ser `JSONObject d3 = status.getJSONObject("d3");` ?

Comment: Eu coloquei assim e funcionou por isso secalhar é suposto

Comment: Eu estou apenas a comentar numa óptica de conseguir que a resposta esteja o mais correta possível. Por isso era certamente um comentário construtivo. Se o `status` está dentro de `obj` se fez `obj.getJSONObject(` para o ir buscar, então para buscar o `d3` dentro de `status` faria sentido ser `status.getJSONObject(`. Ou sou eu que estou a pensar mal?

Comment: @Isac, sim vc está correto acabei colocando o nome incorreto Obrigado pelo toque já corrigi agora está correto! :)

Comment: @EzequielMessore Sem problema. Agora ficou melhor. Dei-lhe o meu +1 também.